# Ranking Data Based on Other Results

Tags: python, sorting, ranking

I have two sets of data in the below code that are linked - 5 'networks', and 5 singular results through 'TT' values. Each TT value corresponds to a network set (e.g. TT1=100 is a result from network1).

My goal is to be able to rank the 5 networks based on the TT results.

```
network1 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]
network2 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]
network3 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]
network4 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]
network5 = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]

networks = [network1, network2, network3, network4, network5]

TT1 = 100
TT2 = 70
TT3 = 80
TT4 = 105
TT5 = 120

TTranks = [TT1,TT2,TT3,TT4,TT5]

s = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(set(TTranks)))}
ranks = [s[x] for x in TTranks] 
print(ranks)
```

The results below from this process rank the TT values only, although I am unsure how to link it so that the corresponding networks are also ranked appropriately.

```
[2, 0, 1, 3, 4]
```

That is, I would like it to then rank the 5 networks as network2, network3, network1, network4, network5.
This will be very useful as I would like to be able to call from the ordered network results later on.

Additionally, is there a more effective way of completing this process?

I appreciate all the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `key` optional argument of the `sort`/`sorted` functions to sort according to a custom value.

### Code

```py
network1 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]
network2 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]
network3 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]
network4 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]
network5 = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]

networks = [network1, network2, network3, network4, network5]

TT1 = 100
TT2 = 70
TT3 = 80
TT4 = 105
TT5 = 120

TT = [TT1, TT2, TT3, TT4, TT5]

sorted_networks_with_indices = sorted(enumerate(networks), key=lambda t: TT[t[0]])

sorted_indices = [i for i,n in sorted_networks_with_indices]
sorted_networks = [n for i,n in sorted_networks_with_indices]

print(sorted_indices)
print(sorted_networks)
```

### Output:

```
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4]
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

### Code explanation

`enumerate(networks)` lists the pairs `i,n` where `i` is the index and `n` the network. These pairs are sorted with the `sorted` function, and the key used to sort is `lambda t: TT[t[0]]`. Here `t` is the pair `i,n`, so `t[0]` is the index `i`. Therefore `TT[t[0]]` is the TT corresponding to index-network pair `t`.

### Note about 0-index

The indices in `sorted_indices` are `[1, 2, 0, 3, 4]` and not `[2, 3, 1, 4, 5]` because python lists are 0-indexed, but this corresponds to network2, network3, network1, network4, network5. If you are not happy with that you can replace the relevant line with:

`sorted_indices = [i+1 for i,n in sorted_networks_with_indices]`

### References

- The `sorted` function and its `key` argument: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted
- The `sort` member of `list` and its `key` argument: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and explanation, I really appreciate it! I think this works exactly as I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain how networks and TTranks are connected? The code shows no dependency on these two.

You simply want the indices for sorting TTranks? Then you should avoid set(TTranks), since the order will not be preserved in a set, also duplicates will be deleted. There are several ways to get the sorting indices, I prefer argsort from numpy:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.argsort(TTranks)) 
# [1 2 0 3 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That definitely is a more efficient and clear approach. In terms of the connection between the networks and TT values, they are separately input within the code at the moment - this is where I am a bit stuck as I would like to have a link between them so I can rank the networks based on the TT indices.